# Show actual numbers on bars when X axis is of percentage values (Flot bar charts)

Tags: jquery, flot

Is it possible to have the axis show % values from serioes data and yet the inside of the bars show as actual values in Flot horizontal bar charts

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean by saying `actual numbers`. Please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small nice plugin:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/oyitub/1/edit)*

[image: jQuery bars plugin]

(Gold is the element's BG color, while jQuery animates the same element's BG image (grad.azure one))

```
<div class="bar">66%</div>
<div class="bar bar5">4.5</div>
```

basic CSS:

```
.bar{
  width:300px;
  height:20px;
  background:#444 url(barBG.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat;
  color:#fff;
}
```

> Small tip: make sure your BG image's width is at least wide as the element desired width, so e.g. `0%` will be fully covered.

jQuery plugin:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.bars = function( opts ) {  
    var set = $.extend( {
      'max': 100
    }, opts );
    return this.each(function(){ 
      var $this = $(this);
      var barW = $this.width();
      var val = parseFloat( $this.text().replace(',','.') );
      var ratio = ( val/set.max*barW );          
      $this.stop().animate({backgroundPosition: ratio+'px'},600);             
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

```
$('.bar').bars(); // default rates = 100
$('.bar5').bars({max:5});
```

Comment: Thanks hey, Is it possible to put actual values on top of the bars although the bars are created with percentage values?